# Rewriting extensionless URLs to .Rmd with R Shiny server on nginx

Tags: r, nginx, shiny, ubuntu-18.04, shiny-server

I have nginx listening on port 80 and an R Shiny Server behind a firewall at port 3838. There is a reverse proxy to send all requests to the `/internal` directory through a password dialog on the browser before it goes to the Shiny server.

I am trying to figure out how to turn URLs that the user enters like `http://my.domain/internal/SomeProgram` to `http://my.domain/internal/SomeProgram.Rmd` so that the Shiny server can process them. I don't know whether to use `try_files` or something like:

```
if (!-e $request_filename) {
    rewrite ^(.*)$ /$1.Rmd;     
}
```

This part below works, but I don't know where or how to insert the above code (or use completely different code) to make the extensionless to `.Rmd` conversion:

```
location /internal {
  auth_basic "Admin Area";
  auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/.htpasswd;
  proxy_pass http://localhost:3838/internal/;
  proxy_redirect / $scheme://$http_host/;
}

location /shiny/ {
  rewrite ^/shiny/(.*)$ /$1 break;
  proxy_pass http://localhost:3838/;
  proxy_redirect / $scheme://$http_host/;
  proxy_http_version 1.1;
  proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
  proxy_set_header Connection $connection_upgrade;
  proxy_read_timeout 20d;
  proxy_buffering off;
}
```

Any insights would be greatly appreciated. Thanks :)

Comment: Can the Nginx server see the `.Rmd` files within its document root, in which case you could use `try_files`? e..g. `try_files $uri $uri.Rmd =404;`

Comment: I did try that (before and after the `auth_basic` lines in the `internal` block) but it directed everything to 404s... with current nginx settings, the `.Rmd` loads just fine, so I know it is there and visible in the docroot.

Comment: Try: `rewrite ^(.*)$ /$1.Rmd break;` inside the `location /internal` block.

Comment: The `rewrite` didn't do it... with `permanent` or `last` or `break`. I'll try some more possibilities but problem is still as of yet unsolved.